# Can someone tell me why i'm having this error when creating my array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Well, I'm having a problem where I created an array using JavaScript with 3 values and 3 sub values but when I try to add more than 3 values, I get this unexpected error. Does anyone have an idea to why it does this? I'm new to JavaScript and I really would like some help with this! I would greatly appreciate it.
[My Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grp6L.png)
[The error it gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYJIh.png)

I added three other values inside my array variable and I get an error saying this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Try creating a snippet here inside SO, click `<>` and it allows you copy paste code to run directly here for others to see.  Pictures of code & errors are not that useful for us to help.

Comment: image of code is not code --> https://idownvotedbecau.se  /  Images of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**,** is missed after `, "Gaithersburg"]` in your code

```
var myArray = [
  ["23 de diciembre", "Comienzan solo clases en línea", "Rockville"],
  ["13 de diciembre",
    "Comienzan las clases en línea en el campus y en sesiones cortas","Takoma"],
  ["6 de enero", "Comienza el semestre de primavera", "Gaithersburg"],
  ["December 10, 2023", "Web development workshop <<< Click Here", "2:00pm - 4:30pm"],
  ["December 15, 2023", "Holiday coding challenge <<< Click Here", "All day"],
  ["December 20, 2023", "Networking event for developers <<< Click Here", "6:00pm - 8:00pm"],
  ["January 5, 2024", "New Year kickoff party <<< Click Here", "8:00pm - 12:00am"],
  ["January 15, 2024", "Machine learning seminar <<< Click Here", "10:30am - 1:00pm"]
];
```

Comment: Please don't write an answer for typos. Such questions are closed and deleted. They are not helpful for future users. You can help the OP with a comment. Where did you find this code in the question?